# Rawsql query array into formatted html table

Tags: python, html, mysql, sql, django

I have done a rawsql query on a table on my database in my views.py and gotten an array looking like this :

```
[
    (19778, 4519, 'sp|P48740|MASP1_HUMAN', 5, 50, 'R'),
    (19779, 14872, 'sp|P48740|MASP1_HUMAN', 5, 54, 'R'),
    (19780, 1018, 'sp|P48740|MASP1_HUMAN', 5, 45, 'R'),
    (19781, 13685, 'sp|P48740|MASP1_HUMAN', 5, 51, 'R'),
]
```

I want to format this into a html table which the 6 section within each set of parentheses each a column. Of course there will be an unknown amount of items in the array so explicitly calling each will not work.

What is the best and most efficient way to do this? Is it `php`, `JavaScript`, doing it within `python`?

Comment: Is using php the best and most efficient option?

Comment: We need more information about your output: do you want to write a HTML file on disc that should contain this HTML table? Or something/somewhere else?

Comment: No I am using it as a template in django so I want it to show on a webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a `Django` template, you could pass the data (which I assume is a `Python` `list`) from the view into the template and render it with something like the following:

In the view you have a list which you pass to your template:

```py
elem_list = [
    (19778, 4519, 'sp|P48740|MASP1_HUMAN', 5, 50, 'R'),
    (19779, 14872, 'sp|P48740|MASP1_HUMAN', 5, 54, 'R'),
    (19780, 1018, 'sp|P48740|MASP1_HUMAN', 5, 45, 'R'),
    (19781, 13685, 'sp|P48740|MASP1_HUMAN', 5, 51, 'R'),
]
```

Then in the template:

```py
<table>
{% for elem in elem_list %}
    <tr>
    {% for sub_elem in elem %}
        <td>{{ sub_elem }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: Yes this works great! However, how would I get lines and such between each element, would that be in a css file? Also how would I get the names of each column at the top?

Comment: @AgentLu The appearence of the table is controlled via CSS, prefferently a separate file; or you could use something like `<table style="border-width: 1px;">`